# Flask-Login: Does not work on local machine but fine on hosting

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have a flask app, and I use flask-login, following tutorials (nothing fancy here)

- works fine on hosting
- works fine on my local MAC computer (at home)
- does not work on my local Linux computer (at office, which may be behind a firewall, but I am able to do port-forwarding and connect to the database)
- does not work on Chrome or Firefox
- does not work if I serve on `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

```
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager 

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.session_protection = "strong"
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

def login():
    error = None
    form = LoginForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = db.users.find_one({"username": form.username.data})
        pass_hash = generate_password_hash(form.password.data)

        if user and User.validate_login( pass_hash,  user['password'] ):
            user_obj = User(user['username'])
            session['logged_in'] = True
            login_user(user_obj,remember=True)
            flash("Logged in successfully", category='success')
            print 'logged in: OK'

            #return redirect(request.args.get("next") or url_for("index"))
            return redirect( url_for("index"))
        error = 'Invalid credentials'
    return render_template('login.html', title='login', **locals())
```

well, when I enter my password wrong, it gives the "Invalid credentials" error. When I enter my password correctly, I do not see **"Logged in successfully"** flash, but on console I see **"logged in OK"**. So there is no problem with DB connection. However I am not logged in. For example,

```
g.user.is_authenticated()
```

gives false in the template (this occurs only on my local Linux, on the other hand hosting and MAC successfully logs in the user).

Comment: Looks like you are using mongodb (but I might be wrong). Can you add  print statements to print user and pass_hash before this line  if user and User.validate_login( pass_hash,  user['password'] ):  or use python debugger to check if the database gives you back what you expect !

Comment: @skippy yes I get all of them correctly, I get user object correctly too.

Comment: Hmmm, so from looking at your code, if you could pass the check "if user and User.validate_login( pass_hash,  user['password'] ):" ,  you should be able to see "Logged in successfully" . So  if you are able to get your objects correctly as expected from your db ,  then you are failing on your "if clause" . To be precise you are failing on this check "User.validate_login( pass_hash,  user['password'] )". Can you step into this code and verify if it is returning a False ?

Comment: @skippy thanks but, I am not failing on if clause. As I mentioned in the question, on console I can see "logged in :OK", so if clause is fine. There has to be something else, that I do not know.

Comment: Oh , I missed it on your description. My bad !  Well , if the flash msg doesn't show up on the web page , you could probably view its html source and check if the msg actually made it there.  Im guessing you are using jinja as your templating engine on the client side and I haven't seen any anomalies with jinja on linux/mac so far.    But if the html source indeed doesn't expand the flash message , I'd be using a client side debugger like Firebug/chrome-debugger to check if there are any exceptions generated. I'd do the same thing on Firefox and Chrome and check if the behavior is consistent

Comment: It sounds like a problem with the session. That would affect both the login and the flash messages. You mentioned port forwarding. Are you forwarding to the same port, e.g., 5000 to 5000, or are you forwarding to a different port, e.g., 80 to 5000?

Comment: @dirn yes looks like something with the session. Yes it is forwarding the same port. Well if I forward to wrong port, it cannot read from the database. But currently it reads from database.

Comment: What's your `User` model? In particular, what is your implementation of `is_authenticated()`?

Answer (score 2):

Where and how are you saving the session in the browser?

Consider a session stored in a browser cookie for the production domain `example.com`, which you have also configured locally (by adding an override to your `/etc/hosts` file).

If your office server is configured to use a different subdomain, for example `office.example.com`, and `REMEMBER_COOKIE_DOMAIN` is set to `example.com`, the office server will not be able to read the cookie. The fix is to use a cross-domain cookie: `REMEMBER_COOKIE_DOMAIN=.example.com` (note the preceding dot).

Ref: https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#cookie-settings

Answer (score 1):

With sessions come session management...

- Are you using a client-based session management?

  - possible issues with the cookies e.g. [cookie size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552418/flask-session-forgets-entry-between-requests), [too much data in cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100315/flask-session-member-not-persisting-across-requests)
  - possible issues with the server secret key e.g. generating a new secret key each time
- Are you using server-based session management (e.g. [flask-kvsession](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-KVSession/))?

  - possible issues trying to access the same backend as prod e.g. firewall preventing access to a redis server

It is possible that you are trying to store more session data when hitting your dev server (e.g. longer server urls, debug data, etc...), which can be a pain to deal with when session management is done on the client.