# Flask session not persisting between requests for Angular App

Tags: python, angular, session, flask

I have an Angular app that needs to call a Flask server that use sessions to store information between requests.

I also have an older JS app that called the same server using XMLHttpRequest, that I am replacing with the new Angular app.

The trouble is that when the old app was making a request, session cookies were working as expected but now with the angular app it does not.

All interactions are done over localhost. The Flask server is accessible from `localhost:5000`, and the Angular app from `localhost:4200`.

The old app was doing request like this:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:5000/api/getAll", true);
xhttp.withCredentials = true;
xhttp.send();
```

The Angular app is doing like so:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const httpOptions = {
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'charset': 'UTF-8',

    })
};


@Injectable()
export class ServerService {
  url = "http://localhost:5000/api/"

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getAll(): Observable<string>{
    return this.http.get<string>(this.url + 'getAll', httpOptions);
  }

  login (username: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.post<string>(this.url + 'login', JSON.stringify({"username": username}), httpOptions)
  }

}
```

And the Flask server:

```
from flask import Flask, session, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import os
import Person
import multiprocessing as mp
import json
import Insurance
import datetime
import Functions
import missingVal


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)

# set the secret key. keep this really secret:
# The value come from calling os.urandom(24)
# See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18709356/3729797 for more information
# app.secret_key = b'fL\xabV\x85\x11\x90\x81\x84\xe0\xa7\xf1\xc7\xd5\xf6\xec\x8f\xd1\xc0\xa4\xee)z\xf0'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = b'fL\xabV\x85\x11\x90\x81\x84\xe0\xa7\xf1\xc7\xd5\xf6\xec\x8f\xd1\xc0\xa4\xee)z\xf0'




@app.route('/api/getAll')
def getAll():
    response = jsonify()
    if 'username' in session:
        user = users[session['username']]
        # some more logic here
        response = jsonify({'username': session['username']})

    return response

# login and account creation    
@app.route('/api/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    response = jsonify()
    if users.get(request.json.get('username')) is not None:
        session['username'] = request.json.get('username')
        # some more logic here
        response = jsonify({'username': session['username']})

    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
                         'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
                         "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-auth")
    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # some more logic here
    app.run(host='localhost', threaded=True
```

The problem is that when I log in, it push information into the session, and when I do another request, I check if that information is in the session but it does not.

I found a lot of other related question on StackOverflow:

- [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18709213/3729797) has to do with setting the secret_key multiple times, which is not my problem.
- [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22675084/3729797) talk about static versus dynamic configuration in init but I don't think it has anything to do with my problem? Tell me if I'm wrong.
- [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15552418/3729797) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7100315/3729797) had trouble because their payload inside the cookie was too big, only 4096bytes or less are allowed it seems. But I only put a username that is a few letters into my cookie so I don't believe it is my problem.
- [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13760008/3729797) I thought was related to my problem because it deals with localhost, but it turns out that it was because OP was mixing requests on `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` and cookies are processed separately by flask apparently. I do all my request on `localhost` so not related I believe.

I'm a bit lost right now, there is probably something very obvious I am missing but can't figure it out, any suggestion appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working by adding

```
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
                         "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-auth")
```

in the Flask server before sending back all requests.

For example

```
@app.route('/api/doSomething', methods=['POST'])
def doSomething():
    response = jsonify()
    if 'username' in session:
        # some logic here
        response = jsonify(someData)

    # here is the line I added
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
                         "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-auth")
    return response
```

Apparently it is needed when doing CORS, some good informations on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)